# Adding through an array with np.where function Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I am trying to write a function where it adds the `Sequence` one at a time until the `Number` is reached. So since the the sum of the `Sequence` array is 21 and not 45 it will add the first element of the `Sequence` 3 to the `Sequence` so it becomes `[3, 7, 11, 3]`. Since `[3, 7, 11, 3]` is equal to 24 and is lower than 45 the next element in the Sequence is going to be added which is 7, the `Sequence` is updated to be `[3, 7, 11, 3, 7]` and so on until `Number> np.sum([Sequence]` is does not return `True`. The `np.where` function below is faulty how can I fix it?

Code:

```
Number = 45
Number2= 46
Sequence = np.array([3, 7, 11])
p = 0
np.where(Number> np.sum([Sequence]),np.append(Sequence,Sequence[p], p+= 1))
np.where(Number2> np.sum([Sequence]),np.append(Sequence,Sequence[p], p+= 1))
```

Expected Output

```
Number = [3,7,11,3,7,11,3]
Number2 = [3,7,11,3,7,11,3,7]
```

Comment: Python evaluates function arguments first, and then passes in the results. `where` is a function, not an iterator.  Practice with `where` in an interactive session before trying to do something fancy like this.

Comment: Except for functions like `np.cumsum` most `numpy` functions operate on their inputs 'in-parallel', as whole arrays..  They do not operate sequentially.  Lists are better for sequential tasks like yours.

Comment: Is there anyway I could implant what I am trying to do with a pandas module or np.cumsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this can be done as a one-liner.  The second and third parameters to `np.where` are supposed to be sequences.  It's easy as a loop:

```
seq45 = []
for n in itertools.cycle(Sequence):
    seq45.append(n)
    if sum(seq45) >= 45: break
```

Comment: I am trying to use numpy functions since its more optimized but thanks anyways.

Comment: Confucious say, a working non-optimal solution is better than a non-working optimized solution....  You can of course make seq45 an np.array.