# Optimizing Vanilla Python with Pandas and Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, numba

Is there anyway that I could make the function below faster and more optimized with `pandas` or `numpy`, the function below adds the sum of `seq45` until the elements of it is equivalent or over 10000.The elements that is being added up to `seq45` are `3,7,11` in order. The reason why i want to increase the speed is to have have to possibly test 10000 with larger number values like 1000000 and to be processed faster. The answer to this code was gotten from this issue: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487120/adding-through-an-array-with-np-where-function-numpy-python?noredirect=1#comment117539177_66487120)

Code:

```
Sequence = np.array([3, 7, 11])
seq45= []
for n in itertools.cycle(Sequence):
    seq.append(n)
    if sum(seq45) >= 10000: break
        
print(seq45)
```

Current Perfromance/ Processing time: 71.9ms

[image]

Comment: The intelligent answers are the ones below, which take advantage of the mathematics of the situation.  You don't really have to go through 100,000 iterations.  You know that you will have 100000//(3+7+11) complete sets, so you only have to check the leftovers one by one.  That will work instantly even with 1,000,000,000 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Sequence = np.array([3, 7, 11])
s = Sequence.sum()
tot = 10000

seq = list(Sequence)*(tot//s)
mod = tot%s
for n in seq:
    if mod > 0:
        seq.append(n)
        mod -= n
    else:
        break
```

Wall time: 57 µs

Comment: Fun fact: testing this and my own answer (which are, as pointed out, not precisely equivalent), shows this answer to be slightly faster than using `np.tile`. But only for `tot` up to about a million. For larger `tot` values, `np.tile` starts to win (my guess is that `list(Sequence) * (tot//s)` will be expensive), but still only by a small margin. For some things, Python is well optimised.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

tot = 10_000
sequence = np.array([3, 7, 11])
n = tot // sequence.sum() + 1
seq45 = np.tile(sequence, n)
```

Note that this is not exactly equivalent, since it repeats the full sequence, not individual elements, and `seq45` may thus be slightly larger.